# Cassandra / Solr time series data model

Tags: solr, cassandra, time-series, datastax-enterprise

I have question regarding the timeseries data model with DSE Search. I am trying to leverage Cassandra's advantage of wide rows with aggregated time data per row. DSE docs states that “Cassandra time series type rows” are not supported in DSE search.

http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise3.1/solutions/dse_search_benefits#unsupported-features

Does that mean wide rows aren’t supported ? I assume the time series rows are typically wide rows with variable number of columns per row like (Row Key : 1 day’s data as columns); which means that one row of this data would be a Solr document and the variable no of columns would be dynamic fields in Solr doc. Now the question is there a way to select only subset of fields based on the values in those fields ? Also, are there good design recommendations to model and query time series data in DSE Search ?

Thanks,
Amey

Answer (score 1):

Wide rows will be supported with the CQL3 + Solr integration, which will be released soon.  DSE also has the capability of modifying the input and output from C* to Solr using pluggable classes (currently undocumented), however for wide rows that would be considered experimental (as no one has tried it before).